# Is there any way to display list of Metadata Componants which are Last Modified or Created recently?

Tags: deployment, metadata

My requirement is that I need to display org metadata components (like Objects, Apex Classes, VF Pages, Record Types, Profiles, Permission Sets, Custom Object, Custom Fields, Custom Label ...etc) on my VF page.

Does anybody have any idea regarding this? How can I achieve this? I have thought of the Metadata API but it only allows to fetch the Page Layouts and Custom Metadata Records as of now. So any other ideas are highly appreciated.

Thanks
Nirav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MetadataService.cls` to get all this info. For example, you can check method `readCustomObject()` in https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataServiceExamples.cls. to get all the objects info.

Source : https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi

Comment: Thanks, will try with this

Comment: Thanks this helps me...

Comment: Hi @salesforce-sas, the MetadataService.cls helps me a lot, but is it possible to filter the List of metadata by its Last Modified date. I mean to say I need the list of all Metadata which for which the last modified date is greater than last month